# Vue js - VueToasted global is empty after registering a new function

Tags: vuejs2

I have a toast.js file made in this way

```
import Toasted from 'vue-toasted'
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.use(Toasted)

// Lets Register a Global Error Notification Toast.

// options to the toast
let errorOptions = {
  type: 'error',

  duration: 5000,
  position: 'top-center'
}

let successOptions = {
  type: 'success',

  duration: 5000,
  position: 'top-center'
}

// register the toast with the custom message
Vue.toasted.register('echarge_error',
  (payload) => {
    console.log('registrata')
    // if there is no message passed show default message
    if (!payload.message) {
      return 'Oops.. Something Went Wrong..'
    }

    // if there is a message show it with the message
    return payload.message
  },
  errorOptions
)

// register the toast with the custom message
Vue.toasted.register('echarge_success',
  (payload) => {
    // if there is no message passed show default message
    if (!payload.message) {
      return 'Oops.. Something Went Wrong..'
    }

    // if there is a message show it with the message
    return payload.message
  },
  successOptions
)
```

So i think i have registered these 2 function for Toasted.

Than, as for the documentation, i try to call them in my components in this way

```
this.$toasted.global.echarge_success({
    message : res.data.message
    })
```

but the `this.$toasted.global` object is empty
The problem is that i registered it not in my main.js? How can i import it, it is not a plugin..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it like this?

```
Vue.prototype.$toasted = echarge_success()
//...
```

For SSR, try the following:

```
Vue.mixin({
    BeforeCreate() {
        This.$toasted = echarge_success()
    }
})
```